# Eclipse used whole C Drive Windows

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed eclipse and java in C drive before and I had 40 GB free space on that time,

Right now I saw C drive become full and consumed whole 40gb as well, so now I have shifted eclipse to D drive of windows,
But still its showing window is out of memory, C drive is still full,

What kind of files is remaining in C drive because of eclipse?

I have tried to delete old eclipse from C drive as well but still after every 2nd day C drive becoming full

These kind of folders are still auto-creating in C drive

[Check this image of C drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMjtf.png)

Comment: Check the path of your workspace.

Comment: Path is of D drive only, already changed

Comment: I mean workspace.  Open eclipse, `File -> Switch Workspace`, then you can see the path of your workspace.

Comment: Sounds like you use Windows and it has an amazing feature for sucking disk spaces dry. It's called "Windows Update". Make sure you are not a victim of it.

Comment: windirstat to see what large files are taking up space.

Comment: 萝莉w When I click File -> Switch Workspace then C drive workspace path also showing, I can delete the C drive workspace from eclipse?

Comment: Seeker windows update is already off mate

Comment: How did you conclude it's the fault of Eclipse and not of some other software?